# Realistic float value for "about zero"

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point-precision

I'm working on a program with fairly complex numerics, mostly in numpy with complex datatypes.  Some of the calculation are returning nearly empty arrays with a complex component that is almost zero.  For example:

```
(2 + 0j, 3+0j, 4+3.9320340202e-16j)
```

Clearly the third component is basically 0, but for whatever reason, this is the output of my calculation and it turns out that for some of these nearly zero values, `np.is_complex()` returns True.  Rather than dig through that big code, I think it's sensible to just apply a cutoff.  My question is, what is a sensible cutoff that anything below should be considered a zero? 0.00?  0.000000? etc...

I understand that these values are due to rounding errors in floating point math, and just want to handle them sensibly.  What is the tolerance/range one allows for such precision error?  I'd like to set it to a parameter:

```
ABOUTZERO=0.000001
```

Comment: This is a primarily opinion-based question.  A reasonable answer would also depend on the requirements of your application - what may be sensible for one application could be a disaster for another.

Comment: The answer to this is entirely specific to your problem and the expected rounding errors.  In general, you should try to give relative bounds, e.g. don't consider the imaginary part to be zero if it is less than some epsilon, but rather consider it zero if the ratio imag/real is less than epsilon.  The specifics on what ratio to choose again depend on the specifics of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the ratio idea is smart.

Hmm, we're doing optics calculations, and in principle the imaginary components could vary across any value, but for most real materials, we get calculations that are about 0.0001 units at the smallest value.  So I'll just use an arbitrary cutoff like this that's larger than e-16.

Comment: On 32bit processor, what would be the number of decimals someone's float32 would have with precision?  (Sorry, not cs-savy at all)

Comment: Python doesn't use a float32 type, but if you're getting values from somewhere else you can expect about 7 decimal digits - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats

Comment: @MarkRansom Plain Python floats are always double-precision (well, unless you compile a custom version of the interpreter), but numpy floats might be single-precision (`np.float32`) or even 16-bit (`np.float16`).

Comment: All my data should be from numpy arrays, which should default to float32 (I think).  So 7 decimals I'll stick with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, what constitutes 'almost zero' really does depend on your particular application, and how large you expect the rounding errors to be.

If you must use a hard threshold, a sensible value might be the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), which is defined as the upper bound on the relative error due to rounding for floating point operations. Intuitively, it is the smallest positive number that, when added to 1.0, gives a result >1.0 using a given floating point representation and rounding method.

In numpy, you can get the machine epsilon for a particular float type using [`np.finfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html):

```
import numpy as np

print(np.finfo(float).eps)
# 2.22044604925e-16
print(np.finfo(np.float32).eps)
# 1.19209e-07
```

Comment: And an unfortunate person w/ a 32 bit processer would have np.float32 as their most precise, right?  Like even if my computer is using float64's

Comment: I believe that a numpy double is the same thing as a C double, which ought to always be 64 bit, regardless of whether your architecture is 64 or 32 bit.